# Using Basic Authorization as Middleware PSR-7 PSR-15

Tags: php, architecture, middleware

TD;LR: I'm trying to grasp the idea behind middleware implementation. It appears to be working but how do I properly handle the response so it shows a Basic Authorization login prompt to the browser?

--

I'm using:

- [equip/dispatch](https://github.com/equip/dispatch)
  for PSR-15 middleware dispatcher
- [guzzlehttp/psr7](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7)
  for PSR-7 ServerRequestInterface
- [middlewares/http-authentication](https://github.com/middlewares/http-authentication)
  sample basic authorization middleware
- [middlewares/response-time](https://github.com/middlewares/response-time)
  additional dummy middleware (to check if also gets executed in the pipeline)

Running the code below:

```
$middleware = [
    new \Middlewares\ResponseTime(),
    (new \Middlewares\BasicAuthentication([
        'username1' => 'password1',
        'username2' => 'password2'
    ]))->attribute('username')
];

// Default handler for end of collection
$default = function (\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest $request) {
    // Any implementation of PSR-7 ResponseInterface
    return new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response();
};

$collection = new \Equip\Dispatch\MiddlewareCollection($middleware);

// Any implementation of PSR-7 ServerRequestInterface
$request = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest::fromGlobals();
$response = $collection->dispatch($request, $default);

print_r($response);
```

Returns the following:

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
(
    [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Unauthorized
    [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 401
    [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [WWW-Authenticate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Basic realm="Login"
                )

            [X-Response-Time] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16.176ms
                )

        )

    [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [www-authenticate] => WWW-Authenticate
            [x-response-time] => X-Response-Time
        )

    [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 
)
```

It appears `middlewares/response-time` and `middlewares/http-authentication` were executed just fine. However, I am under the impression that `middlewares/http-authentication` will show an actual login prompt like this:

[image]

But it didn't. I am suppose to implement that myself? If yes, how can I do that properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the realm to 'My realm'.

```
$middleware = [
    new \Middlewares\ResponseTime(),
    (new \Middlewares\BasicAuthentication([
        'username1' => 'password1',
        'username2' => 'password2'
    ]))->attribute('username')->realm('My realm')
];
```

The GuzzleHttp request happens in the backend so it won't work like it normally would work in a browser  e.g. prompting for username and password. You are basically imitating a request when you use Guzzle without using any browsers. As such if you want the prompt you will have to implement this logic without using GuzzleHttp.

You can still test it with Guzzle as per below.

> The below code will work.

```
$request = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest::fromGlobals()->withHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '.base64_encode('username1:password1'));
$response = $collection->dispatch($request, $default);
echo $response->getStatusCode(); //200
echo $response->getReasonPhrase(); // OK
```

> The below code will fail.

```
$request = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest::fromGlobals()->withHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '.base64_encode(''IncorrectUser:IncorrectPassword''));
$response = $collection->dispatch($request, $default);
echo $response->getStatusCode(); //401
echo $response->getReasonPhrase(); // Unauthorized
```

The best way to implement the `BasicAuthentication` would be within a middleware framework.

> Zend Expressive

```
   //Example using your library
   $app->pipe((new \Middlewares\BasicAuthentication([
                    'username1' => 'password1',
                    'username2' => 'password2'
                    ])
            )->attribute('username')->realm('My realm'));

    //Example using other library
    $app->pipe(new Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
        "users" => [
            "root" => "t00r",
            "user" => "passw0rd"
        ]
    ]));
```

Both of the above code work as expected. For e.g. prompting for username and password in the browser and allowing user to view the content when correct credentials are sent. Guzzle is causing issues for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: same, nothing happened, there's no login prompt showing.

Comment: Ok I kinda got it working by adding my own `header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My realm"');` on top then using `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_*']`vars to pass in the request. But is this really the way it's suppose to be done? see my full sample here: https://pastebin.com/Zr3NC9VC

Comment: As it turns out I don't even need to include `->withHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '.base64_encode($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'].':'.$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))` and `->attribute('username')` and `->realm('My realm')`.

Comment: Yes by adding the if statement `if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))... {..}` you are not using guzzle and as such php would be able to capture the username and password via browser. Once the user puts the username and password it will skip the `if` statement and it will pass the captured username and password to guzzle and if validated by `BasicAuthentication` it should proceed further. I cannot see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I have tested it with a middleware framework like Zend expressive for which the libraries like `BasicAuthentication` is written and it works as expected. For e.g it prompts me with the username and password in the browser, and upon correct submission let me view the page, similar to what you want. I have provided the working example for Zend Expressive.